# How to skip specifying port in Node.js http.request

Tags: node.js, rest, port, netsuite

I am using node.js to connect to NetSuite's REST api. Issue is, I dont know what is port number in NetSuite.. so I want to skip specifying port number. When I dont provide a port number, it takes 80 (default) which is not correct. I have tried port 443 as its https but its not correct port for NetSuite.

I am getting error "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND".  Here is my code.

exports.helloGET = function helloGET (req, res) {

```
//remove extra node

var json_build = '{"__type" : "salesorder", "status":"Approved"}';

console.log(json_build);

//call NS rest api

var options = {
  host: 'rest.na2.netsuite.com',
  path: '/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=55&deploy=1',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Keep-alive': 'timeout=30',
    'Authorization' : 'NLAuth nlauth_account="4678710", nlauth_email="someemail@domain.com", nlauth_signature="password",  nlauth_role="3"'
 }
};

var http = require('http');

var post_req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
  res.on('end',function(){
      console.log('response ended');
  });
});

post_req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
//post data
post_req.write(json_build);
post_req.end();
```

};

It goes inside "post_req.on error".

Comment: You need to figure out the port number as it is not possible to establish a connection without knowing port. Defaults for HTTP being 80 while that for HTTPS being 443.

Comment: I have tried 443.. its not working.. waiting for NetSuite to reply me with Port number. Thanks TGW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error ENOTFOUND typically means that the host you are specifying cannot be found in DNS so that may actually be where your error is.  Several possible reasons for this here: [What ENOTFOUND error in an http request, happening time to time, means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272948/what-enotfound-error-in-an-http-request-happening-time-to-time-means).

---

You have to know the port in order to connect.  You cannot skip it.  A TCP connection requires a destination IP address AND a port number.  You can't make a TCP connection (which is what's under an HTTP connection) without the port number.

As you appear to know, the default port for HTTP is port 80 and the default port for HTTPS is 443.  With `http.request()`, it will be port 80 unless you specify the port.  With `https.request()` (note different https module), then it will be 443 if you don't specify the port.

So, the only answer here is for you to find out what port the service is running on that you want to connect to.  If it isn't a well-known port known in advance, then there needs to be a way to query what port it's running on from some other known service or configuration data.

Also, if you're trying to connection to an HTTPS service, you need to use the `https` module, not the `http` module.

Comment: I have requested NetSuite for Port.  Thanks for answer..Okay sure will use https module.

Answer (score 0):

You’re actually not connecting to the correct host.

Use the getdatacenters API to look up the RESTlet host for your account.