# mailchimp - create a subscription form with node js. I got this error

Tags: node.js, mailchimp

Server is running on port 3000

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .us4.list-manage.com
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26) {
>     errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
>     code: 'ENOTFOUND',
>     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
>     hostname: '.us4.list-manage.com'

Comment: Please see why this error may occur
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272948/what-enotfound-error-in-an-http-request-happening-time-to-time-means

Comment: Can you briefly explain the environment in which this occurred

Comment: I'm in the very beginning, this is probably my first proper code. I'm trying to create a subscribe page to incorporate with Mailchimp. When I need to add the URL in 

 var option = {
    url: "https://.us4.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=8b40649865b1164ec11495c43&amp;id=0450856f39",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "user  pass"
    },
    body: jsonData
  };

I'm afraid that this is the wrong URL or I'm not sure which is the problem...